# Dependency 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-noarg:1.4.31' not found in IntelliJ with Maven

Tags: maven, kotlin, intellij-idea

[image]

I added `kotlin-maven-noarg` dependency in `kotlin-maven-plugin`
but IntelliJ generates `Dependency 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-noarg:1.4.31' not found` error.

It's really weird.
The repository, `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-maven-noarg/1.4.31` exist but maven failed to find it.
Could you tell me how to fix it?

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>kapt</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>kapt</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>src/main/java</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                            <annotationProcessorPaths>
<!--                                <annotationProcessorPath>
                                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                                    <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
                                </annotationProcessorPath>-->
                                <annotationProcessorPath>
                                    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                                    <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                                </annotationProcessorPath>
                            </annotationProcessorPaths>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                        <plugin>no-arg</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                    <!--<jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>-->
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
``


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3JVe.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

`Mouse right button` > `Maven` > `Generate Sources and Update Folders`
fixed the issue.
I'm not sure why I have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I faced exact same error.
My code got compiled only after I used Kotlin Version 1.7.0 in pom.xml